# Sonarqube has Blank Generated Lines of Code Metric

Tags: sonarqube

Sonarqube doesn't really seem to have the concept of generated code baked-in to the application, insofar as one must exclude generated code from all the relevant metrics (issues, coverage, etc) manually by adding the same "magic" path (often `file:**/generated/**`).

However, there is a metric that is called "Generated lines of code". I can add this to my components drill-down, next to the vanilla "lines of code" metric.

However, the column is entirely blank for all of my projects, despite having a lot of generated code!

I cannot find any mechanism by which I can configure how it identifies generated lines of code. If possible, I just need to add yet another duplicated reference to `file:**/generated/**`.

Does such a configuration option exist? How does one go about getting the "generated lines of code" metric populated?

Comment: What's your question ? For which language and in which context, you'd like to track those generated lines of code ? FYI, this metric is only fed by the SonarSource COBOL plugin for the time being.

Comment: @FreddyMallet-SonarSource That explains it! The question was how to use it for my project... but the answer is I cannot -- unless it's a COBOL project. What *IS* interesting, is that I don't have the COBOL plugin listed under the installed plugins (in settings), so it's curious that metrics from the plugin are shown.